# VMWare not changing RAM on virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, virtual-memory

It's my first time posting on this platform so I'll try to be as detailed as possible with my question. 
This year I started working with servers and virtual machines for the first time, so I'm just starting to understand the interfaces and different software, but I haven't really experienced any problems until now. 
I use VMware vSphere Web Client to manage the virtual machines. Its Version 6.5.0 Build 4602587, and I access it through Mozilla Firefox version 56.0. The virtual machine runs on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2. Recently I was requested to increase the RAM on the virtual machine. Via the ESXi host I shutdown the virtual machine, proceeded to 'Edit Settings' and changed the amount in the 'Memory' field, then saved the changes. However after rebooting, the amount of RAM shown when logged into the  virtual machine hasn't changed. But the amount on the vSphere Web Client does reflect the change for that virtual machine. A couple days later and the virtual machine still shows the original amount. Is there anything I didn't consider that prevented the changes from taking effect on the machine itself?

Thanks again, and sorry if I've missed any details.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the OS is 64-bit and what was the original amount of RAM and current amount configured in ESXi ?

Comment: It is indeed a 64-bit. The original RAM was sitting at 32Gb and to be increased to 48Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason your RAM was not added is that you are using Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 STANDARD edition which have a upper limit of 32GB RAM.

Maximum: **8 GB** RAM (**Foundation**), **32 GB** RAM (**Standard**), or **2 TB** RAM (**Enterprise, Datacenter and Itanium**)

Visit the link below for more information.

https://www.lewan.com/blog/2010/02/08/microsoft-windows-server-2008-and-2008-r2-maximum-memory-limits

Comment: We only got the change done on the Server OS recently and what you stated seemed to be what was disabling the additional RAM. Windows Server 2012 Essentials would have been a better fit when they initially set up the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two separate ways you can be able to upgrade the memory on vCenter

[VMware KB: Downgrading the virtual machine hardware version in ESX/ESXi](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028019)

[VMware KB: Editing virtual machine settings fails with the error: You cannot use the vSphere client to edit the sett…](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2061336)